# Scope en Python

Tags: python

Sigo un libro sobre `python` pero me resultó una duda sobre el scope, tengo el siguiente código:

```
pi = 3.14
def crear_area(pi = pi):
    def area(r):
        return pi*r*r
    return area

area = crear_area(10)
print(area(10))  #valor de retorno es 314.5
pi = 12
print(area(10))  #valor de retorno es 314.5
```

Me pueden explicar porque el cambio del objeto `pi` no afecto el resultado, por lo que veo `python` si maneja un scope estático.

Comment: El código es confuso. Empezando con el uso de dos variables con el mismo nombre (piu). Y que se supone que es el argumento de crear area? que intentas hacer con `crear_area(10)` ? No deberia ser `crear_area(pi)`?

Comment: @leonbloy, El código lo puse con la intención de que me expliquen como es el proceso del scope si es dinámico o estático, sé que hay dos objetos con el mismo nombre, pero la intención es saber o que me expliquen como python determina el scope of binding, leí por ahí que Python infiere a partir de la inspección del texto en el programa, pero no me quedo muy claro.

Answer (score 5):

Esto es un ejemplo de [clausuras](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clausura_(inform%C3%A1tica)) (*closure* en inglés) y de cómo funcionan.

Cuando defines la función `crear_area`, estás creando una variable local a esa función con nombre `pi` y con valor por defecto `pi` (global):

```
def crear_area(pi = pi):
```

Ahora, dentro de esa función, estás definiendo una segunda función `area` que se devuelve como resultado/objeto:

```
pi = 3.14
def crear_area(pi = pi):
    def area(r):
        return pi*r*r
    return area
```

Como el ámbito (*scope* en inglés) de `area` es exclusivamente dentro de `crear_area` y sus variables, no importa que cambies el valor de la variable global `pi`, porque `area` siempre va a usar la variable local `pi` de `crear_area` que tenía un valor de 3.14 en el momento de su definición.

Y ese es el motivo por el que, aunque cambies el valor de `pi` (global), `print(area(10))` siempre va a devolver lo mismo: las variables internas mantienen su valor dentro de la clausura.

---

Si quieres que tengan valores diferentes, entonces tendrías que crear un nuevo `area` pasando `pi` como parámetro (así no se usaría el valor por defecto sino el nuevo que pasas):

```
pi = 3.14
def crear_area(pi = pi):
    def area(r):
        return pi*r*r
    return area

area = crear_area()
print(area(10))  #valor de retorno es 314.0
pi = 3  #referencia a Futurama
area = crear_area(pi)
print(area(10))  #valor de retorno es 300
```

De este modo estarías creando un nuevo entorno con nuevas variables y se "resetearían" los valores para `area`.

---

Otra posible alternativa, sería no definir la variable local `pi` y así siempre se usaría la global, obteniendo valores diferentes:

```
pi = 3.14
def crear_area():
    def area(r):
        return pi*r*r #ahora este pi es la variable global
    return area

area = crear_area()
print(area(10))  #valor de retorno es 314.0
pi = 3  #referencia a Futurama
print(area(10))  #valor de retorno es 300
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, comprendo muy bien, claro las funciones internas tienen la capacidad de reconocer el valor de los parámetros definidos dentro del closure y esos parámetros serán de ambito local al closure.